# ASP.NET - Difficulty Modifying Http Headers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, httpresponse

I have been working in ASP.NET MVC for a while now, but one thing that has confused me about it is the difficulty involved in modifying HTTP Headers. It is simple enough to *add* headers (`Response.AppendHeader(...);`), and it is very (almost *too*) simple to *remove all* headers (`Response.ClearHeaders();`). But when it comes to modifying and deleting *individual* headers, there's trouble.

What is the technical reason behind the http headers collection being more than (essentially) a simple `Dictionary<string, string>` that gets written to the response stream? Why is it so easy to remove all, but impossible to remove an individual?

**Note** - I am not only concerned with running it on the server (using IIS 7, integrated pipeline mode), but also in development (using Cassini).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .Net Framwork 3.0, IIS 7.0 / integrated mode:

As you may see, the

```
Response
```

object has the

```
Headers
```

property which is typed as a NameValueCollection (I'm not sure why exactly this type was selected) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers

So, theoretically, you can use it to add or remove your header to/from the response as you've outlined in your question.

As I can see from the Response.AddHeader source code (I've used Reflector), there are few additional checks. For example, the method will throw an exception if you're trying to add a handler after the "Flush" method has been called (which is a correct behavior if you think about it).
I'm not sure why Microsoft guys have made the Headers property public and what's the idea behind it. I think it should be at least protected because there is additional logic behind the scenes and in some cases the process is not limited to the simple array item insertion.

Comment: I understand that it works when running under IIS 7.0 / integrated mode, but I am concerned about running it in development (through Cassini), too.